# Force Logout After New User Registration / Password Change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, passwords, identityserver4, logout

How can one force logout a user after the user does a New User Registration or after Change Password.

I have tried the below:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync (IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
```

However, none of the above work!

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought explicitly signing out like that should do the job. Are you able to share the response headers for the request with the above calls in it?

It looks like you're using ASP.Net Identity which has a mechanism for dealing with this already called the security stamp. Basically this is a opaque value (a hash or generated value) that is changed whenever a security specific settings is changed. There's then logic that periodically checks the value held in the auth cookie with the fresh value from the DB and if they differ it invalidates the session. Check out `SecurityStampValidator` in the ASP.Net Identity code.